# Ruby: Why can't I create a new file?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a json file and write to it.

My code looks like this:

```
def save_as_json(object)
    f = File.new('file.json')
    f.puts(object.to_json, 'w')
    f.close
end

save_as_json({'name'=>'fred'})
```

The problem is, I get the following error when I run it:

```
:15:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - file.json (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I'm asking Ruby to create the file but it's complaining that it doesn't exist! What is the correct way to create and write to a file?

Comment: Try `File.write( "file.json", object.to_json )`. This will truncate an existing file or create a new file if one doesn't exist, write the contents to it and close the file.

Comment: Sometimes it's a pathing issue. Compare your file path with what you think the file path is with something like: File.expand_path('my_file.rb')

Answer (score 8):

You just need to open the file using the 'w' mode like this:

```
f = File.new('file.json', 'w')
```

You want to determine the mode based on what you plan to do with the file, but here are your options:

> "r"  Read-only, starts at beginning of file  (default mode).
>
> "r+" Read-write, starts at beginning of file.
>
> "w"  Write-only, truncates existing file
>        to zero length or creates a new file for writing.
>
> "w+" Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length
>        or creates a new file for reading and writing.
>
> "a"  Write-only, each write call appends data at end of file.
>        Creates a new file for writing if file does not exist.
>
> "a+" Read-write, each write call appends data at end of file.
>        Creates a new file for reading and writing if file does
>        not exist.

[IO Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)

Answer (score 2):

File creation defaults to read mode, so trying to use a filespec that does not exist will result in an error:

```
2.3.0 :001 > f = File.new 'foo'
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - foo
```

You need to specify 'w':

```
2.3.0 :002 > f = File.new 'foo', 'w'
 => #<File:foo>
```

That said, there are easier ways to write to files than to get a file handle using `File.new` or `File.open`. The simplest way in Ruby is to call `File.write`:

```
File.write('file.json', object.to_json)
```

You can use the longer `File.open` approach if you want; if you do, the simplest approach is to pass a block to File.open:

```
File.open('file.json', 'w') { |f| f << object.to_json }
```

This eliminates the need for you to explicitly close the file; `File.open`, when passed a block, closes the file for you after the block has finished executing.

Comment: Without a block File.open is the same as File.new.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html#method-c-open

Comment: Wow, you're right, I should have known that.  I will change my answer to reflect that.  Sorry...

Comment: Note that with a call as trivial as File.write, there is no longer a need to write a separate wrapper method to do it.